# Delphi - non-data-aware control reverts dataset to browse state

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I have a a form with a TEdit and a TDBGrid attached to a TDataSource wich in turn, is attached to a TClientDataSet. I set the TClientDataSet.State to dsAppend and afterwards I set the Text property of the TEdit with an empty string. When I trace the code, after setting the empty string the TClientDataSet.State have reverted to dsBrowse. It is possible that that assignment can change the TClientDataSet.State?

Comment: Can you add simple event handlers for the dataset's AfterInsert, BeforeCancel, BeforePost etc. to log what's happening and when?

Comment: No, this is not possible. (There is no connection between setting a TEdit.Text to '' and changing a TDataSet.State.) You have something else happening in your code. As you've posted none, it's pretty difficult to help debug it. :-)